# How to dynamically position an absolute div?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a 1000px page width, my header contains 10 horizontal nav elements using `justify-content: space-between`.
If I hover `nav 1` link, an absolute menu div will appear width a specific width and `left: 0`, if I hover `nav 2`, another menu div will appear still with `left: 0`. But when I hover `nav 7` or `nav 8`, how can I automatically make the menu get aligned right (`right: 0`)?

here is a code snippet of my html & css:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav menu1</a>
      <div class="menu">Content menu 1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav menu2</a>
      <div class="menu">Content menu 2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav menu3</a>
      <div class="menu">Content menu 3</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav menu4</a>
      <div class="menu">Content menu 4</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav menu5</a>
      <div class="menu">Content menu 5</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav menu6</a>
      <div class="menu">Content menu 6</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav menu7</a>
      <div class="menu">Content menu 7</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav menu8</a>
      <div class="menu">Content menu 8</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav menu9</a>
      <div class="menu">Content menu 9</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav menu10</a>
      <div class="menu">Content menu 10</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


ul {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 24px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

ul > li {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: #333;
    width: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  min-height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  transition-delay: .3s;
  left: 0;
  top: 140%;
  z-index: 99999;
}

ul > li:hover .menu {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is missing a lot of information including the code you are working with. It seems you may be looking for the nth child pseudo class to define a range.

The following is generic as you have not provided an HTML sample and will affect the 6th to 10th children.

CSS:

```
 li:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+10){
 right:0;
 }
```

**Edit: Updated answer now that the question is clearer...**

See the below example with added (vanilla) Javascript.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
ul{
display:flex;
  font-size:15px;
  height:100%;
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  max-width:1200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:24px;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
ul > li{
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding-left:6px;
  padding-right:6px;
  height:40px;
  align-items:center;
  white-space:nowrap;
  list-style:none;
}
.menu{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  visibility:hidden;
  color:#333;
  width:500px;
  background:#fff;
  padding:18px;
  min-height:80px;
  box-shadow:0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  opacity:0;
  transition:all .4s ease;
  transition-delay:.3s;
  top:140%;
}
ul > li:hover .menu{
  display:block;
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  top:100%;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<nav>
 <ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Nav menu1</a>
    <div class="menu">Content menu 1</div>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Nav menu2</a>
    <div class="menu">Content menu 2</div>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Nav menu3</a>
    <div class="menu">Content menu 3</div>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Nav menu4</a>
    <div class="menu">Content menu 4</div>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Nav menu5</a>
    <div class="menu">Content menu 5</div>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Nav menu6</a>
    <div class="menu">Content menu 6</div>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Nav menu7</a>
    <div class="menu">Content menu 7</div>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Nav menu8</a>
    <div class="menu">Content menu 8</div>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Nav menu9</a>
    <div class="menu">Content menu 9</div>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Nav menu10</a>
    <div class="menu">Content menu 10</div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<script>
var elems=document.querySelectorAll('div.menu');  //Get NodeList of elements
elems.forEach(function(elem){                     //Iterate
var pos=elem.getBoundingClientRect();             //Get element info
let stat=document.elementFromPoint(pos.right,0);  //Check position
if(stat===null){                                  //Will be null if out of viewport
elem.style.right='0';                             //Add the right:0; style
}else{
elem.style.left='0';                              //Add the left:0; style
}});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 2: As requested, just change the JavaScript to check against the container.**

As it is now this will match against the first `<ul>` found in the document. You will probably want to `<ul id="cont">` and match with the id instead:

```
<script>
//var cont=document.getElementById('cont');       //Match by ID
var cont=document.querySelector('ul');            //Match first <ul>

var posc=cont.getBoundingClientRect();            //Get container info
var elems=document.querySelectorAll('div.menu');  //Get NodeList of elements
elems.forEach(function(elem){                     //Iterate
var posv=elem.getBoundingClientRect();            //Get element info
var offset=posc.right-posv.right;                 //Calculate difference
if(offset<0){                                     //Will be <0 if out of container
elem.style.right='0';                             //Add the right:0; style
}else{
elem.style.left='0';                              //Add the left:0; style
}});
</script>
```

Comment: You have given every reason why you should be voting to close the question and no reason for answering it. Not every question should be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Sorry, I thought i was clear without posting any code! I have updated my question with a minimal code. As you can see when I hover Nav menu8 or 9, the menu goes beyond the border! I4ve already thought about the nth child but I would like something more automatic or dynamic depending on the viewport. Maybe some JS is required?

Comment: indeed I haven't seen it, thank you very much, it works like a charm :) there is one lil' details, if you go to this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VOqOqg you'll notice that when you hover Nav menu 7, the right side of the overlay goes beyond the menu red border. any idea how to change that so it can be calculated regarding the red border? For info, I'm using vuejs, just in case you have a better solution with vuejs :) Thanks

Comment: @Websphere - No problem, modified Javascript added.

Comment: @JBES wow, you're a genious :) thank you vet much :) I would have 1 last question/ advice please: in this same example, as you may have noticed, i set the `<li>` as `position:relative` so the menu overlay could be positioned at the left edge of its nav menu, and then set a fixed with of `.menu` which is not very responsive for mobiles. is that a good way to do so? or is there a better practice?

Comment: @Websphere - This [pure CSS responsive dropdown menu](https://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/RNeydj) is probably what you are looking for, that can be adapted with the JavaScript provided to achieve the results you require.